# Simple Way to Using Jade Templates Without Node?

Tags: node.js, pug

## tl;dr

Is there a way to use Jade completely client-side like any of the other JavaScript template engines (e.g., Mustache, Handlebars or Nunjucks), so that it loads includes via ajax?

## More Info:

I have a web application that is not running on Node (unfortunately due to various vendors not providing libraries for Node yet) and I have really started liking the syntax and capabilities of Jade. Unfortunately, it seems like everything in Jade requires Node in some capacity, either in the development flow or on the server side. I definitely cannot use it server-side and would prefer not to introduce it to the development cycle just for templating.

It seems like all that would be necessary is to package up the dependencies (this can be done with browserify) and to implement fs to read files with ajax. Is there some implementation of this already?

Also, the time taken to compile once per file, per session is not really a concern for this application.

Comment: There are other ways to compile jade than node. See the bottom of the [Jade github page](https://github.com/jadejs/jade) for a list of implementations in other languages. One of them should be suitable for use with your server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually found out the way to do this, completely on the client side:

1. Use browserify CDN to obtain a client-side bundle for the node package.
2. Implement the 'readFileSync' function in the 'fs' module in the bundle to use a synchronous XmlHttpRequest and retrieve the file from the server (it is currently empty so no function exists)

Viola!

**UPDATE:**

Here is my implementation:

```
2:[function(require,module,exports){
module.exports = {
cache: { },
readFileSync: function(path){
  return this.cache[path] || (this.cache[path] = (function(){
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('GET', path + '?_=' + $.time(), false);
    request.send();
    if (request.status === 200) {
      return request.responseText;
    }
    else {
      throw 'Unable to load template: ' + path;
    }
  }).call());
 }
}},{}]
```

Comment: I added the following around line 423 in the Jade 1.11.0 source file:

`2:[function(require,module,exports){
 module.exports = {
    cache: { },
  readFileSync: function(path){
      return this.cache[path] || (this.cache[path] = (function(){
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open('GET', path + '?_=' + $.time(), false);
        request.send();
        if (request.status === 200) {
          return request.responseText;
        }
        else {
          throw 'Unable to load template: ' + path;
        }
      }).call());
  }
 }
},{}]`